# I'm using Smart Report Engine in laravel for report generating

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using this code and it's returning me URL and it looks fine and it creating the folder in `public/sre_reports/`
But after the URL I don't see what to do :

```
public function generatePublicReport() 
{
    try {
        $report = new ReportOptions(Constants::SRE_PUBLIC_REPORT);
        $report->select_tables(array("users"))
               ->set_grouping(array("id"))
               ->select_all_fields();
        $engine = new CustomEngine($report);
        $report_path = $engine->create_report();

        return "Your report URL:" . $report_path;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo "Caught exception message:".  $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

OutPut: Your report URL:https://domainname.com/var/www/html/folder/public/sre_reports/rep1592553829503324/rep1592553829503324.php

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, what do you want it to do?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial.
https://mysqlreportsengine.com/basic-usage-of-php-report-engine-framework/
according to this, I got the final but after I don't know what to do with it. How can I use this URL to generate a report?